# Is it possible to wire a regular power supply cord to a sewing machine motor so I can use it for a Halloween prop?

Tags: power-supply, power, wire

If it is possible to wire a regular cord (power supply) to a sewing machine motor (with a motor speed controller), what volt/amp supply do I need to use?

Comment: Any attempt to answer this question will be a hazard to public safety.

Comment: What is a "regular cord (power supply)"?  What are the power requirements for the sewing machine motor and its speed controller?

Comment: Questions about the usage of consumer products, or components salvaged from them *which are not supported by engineering specifications* are not on topic here and thus not permitted.  There are of course motors where this would be trivial, but also presumably those where it is not readily possible and so drastically unsafe.  What you need is not engineering guidance, but rather *experiential* or *domain* knowledge of the type of sewing machine from which you have salvaged the motor, and that is not what this particular site is about.

Comment: On topic explicitly lists modifying. "consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, ***except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses***"

Comment: @passerby as we've been over many times before, modification questions are only on topic when supported by sufficient information.  This one is has no supporting information at all.  "Modifying" is not a magic bullet, quite the contrary, it indicates a situation where the usual rules for what makes a question answerable are even more likely than usual to need to be applied.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, in order to operate any motor salvaged from an appliance, you need to determine exactly how it is powered in the appliance. Salvage all of the related components and use them to power the motor. If you sufficiently understand how the motor is powered, there may be alternate ways to power the motor However, if you don't get all of the relevant information about the motor and how it is powered and controlled, it may be very difficult to safely use the motor or for anyone to tell you what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

If the sewing machine is as original and good to go, then as long as no-one can get to it when it is on the display, you could consider using the original foot switch and put a brick on it to keep it going...

**BUT this is only IF it cannot be touched by people / children / pets**....